# How to sync Facebook contacts in Android Lollipop on Moto G (2nd Gen)?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, contacts, facebook, motorola-moto-g2

Previously I owned HTC One X on which I had Facebook app installed. In Facebook "App Settings" there was an option called "Sync Contacts". With this option I was able to sync my Facebook contacts with my contacts in Google.

Now I have bought Moto G (2nd Gen) with Android Lollipop. I installed Facebook app but now in "App Settings" I cannot see the option of "Sync Contacts". I still have my HTC One X and its *updated* Facebook app still shows the option of "Sync Contacts" which is not present in Moto G (2nd Gen).

Am I missing something here? How to sync Facebook contacts in Android Lollipop on Moto G (2nd Gen)?

**Update 1:**

I tried the solution indicated in [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/1838/30106) but I cannot see Sync Contacts checkbox in "Accounts > Facebook". Maybe because the device for which the issue is stated, is pretty old.

Comment: @Lucky: As per your linked question I cannot see Sync Contacts checkbox in "Accounts > Facebook". Maybe because the device for which the issue is stated, is pretty old and something might have changed on Android Lollipop.

Comment: Could you mention which Android version is HTC One X running on? Also, have you checked the version of Facebook app on each device? (just want to confirm, since update might not apply to all devices)

Comment: @AndrewT.: My HTC One X is running Android 4.2.2. The Facebook app on both the devices is of version 34.0.0.43.267. In App Settings at the end I can see a setting "Sync Contacts" in HTC One X but not in Moto G (2nd gen). Weird!

Comment: @AndrewT.: Searched a bit more and found [this discussion on Android.SE](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/63748/30106) explaining the issue further. It seems this is a spat between Google and Facebook and user's are caught in between. But it doesn't explain why my Facebook app on HTC One X has "Sync Contacts" settings while on Moto G (2nd gen) does not. Is Facebook selectively hiding the option of "Sync Contacts" from (near) stock Android implementations? Or it gets hidden because the stock Android Contacts app does not have the capability to sync other account contacts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I should searched a bit more before posting this question. But in my defence the answer was in second page of Google search results.

From [this link](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_answer_detail/a_id/102425/p/30,6720,9293) I gather that:

> Facebook contacts will no longer sync with the Android Contacts app
>   [on Android OS 4.1 and later].
>
> The Android Contact list is built to provide data portability, and
>   Facebook provides contact data that cannot be exported from the
>   device.
>
> Facebook contacts can still be accessed on the phone through the
>   Facebook app.

It seems HTC had its own custom Contacts app which made the importing syncing contacts from Facebook (and other social networks) much easier. The Contacts app on Moto G (2nd gen) is stock Android and doesn't seem to have this feature.

The artilcle further suggests:

> While we cannot guarantee or warranty a third-party application, some
>   owners have reported success syncing Facebook contacts using Ubersync
>   and Haxsync.

**NOTE:** The link mentioned earlier refers to Nexus 6 but I believe it applies to other devices also and seems to be the only logical answer as of now.

Comment: I believe this applies to vanilla Android or some custom ROMs. For instance cyanogen mod or other close to stock ROMs. Very frustrating that Facebook consistently ignores any standard practices for its app. They think they know best - they really don't. Every other popular social network has a better app than Facebook.